# Script to prepend all filenames within a directory

Tags: shell, file-rename

I've found an issue with adobes bates numbering tool, where file names are messing up the order in which they are numbered.
I was hoping to write a script that users would be able to click on and add the folder extension for all the files.
Then the script would prepend all the file names within the folder with a 000001filename.pdf      000002filename.pdf   etc...
I've never combined scripts  before but i've found scripts that either rename OR prepend.  and i couldn't find anything that would rename sequentially with preceding 0's.

Comment: and maybe for the popup for the user have a windows explorer popup.. if that's doable.  i'm attempting this right now.  i'll post what i come up with

Comment: So, you want a different 6-digit serially allocated number prefixed to each plain file (as opposed to directory -- what about any other file types?) in the directory, with the order in which the numbers are allocated being largely arbitrary?  Any prohibition on using, say, Perl or Python?  Any need for recursive search?  Any need for controlling starting numbers?  Any need for more than 6 digits, or less?  Also, what did you try and what were the problems you ran into?

Comment: In bash, the printf command would be useful.  It doesn't sound hard in bash, but Jonathan's right, perl or python would be more elegant and flexible if you like one of those tools.

Answer (score 0):

without much testing:

```
n=0 # or 1 if you like
format="%06d" # format of prefix
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | # only one level, no dirs but also no symlinks etc
    cut -d/ -f2 | # remove leading ./
    sort | # plugin your sorting here
    while read file
    do
        prefix=`printf "%06d" $n`
        mv "$file" "$prefix$file" # but mv is dangerous!
        n=$((n+1))
    done
```